# Erro ao cancelar importação de arquivo no Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Estou construindo uma `Macro` para importação de um arquivo no Excel. Em determinado momento, quando é solicitado a localização do arquivo, caso o usuário da *Worksheet* cancele a opção de importação, é retornada a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range

Após isso a execução da macro é encerrada. Verificando o `Debug`. o erro ocorre no parâmetro `.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False` do procedimento.

Abaixo o código de importação:

```
Public Sub btnImportarTXT_Click()

    ' Sub para importar arquivo .TXT

    Dim Dir As String

    dirArquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text File, *.txt")

    With Sheets("Extract").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & dirArquivo, Destination:=Range("Extract!$A$1"))
        .Name = "extract"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 1252
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ' Worksheets("Extract").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

    MsgBox "Arquivo importado!", vbOKOnly, "Sucesso!"

End Sub
```

Comment: E o código usado pra cancelar a importação?

Comment: @Caffé, não existe código. Quando é executado o `dirArquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text File, *.txt")`, é aberta um `Dialog` no Windows para selecionar o arquivo. Quando eu cancelo este `Dialog`, retorna o erro informado acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu comentário explica que "cancelar" trata-se de o usuário cancelar a caixa de diálogo que pede que um arquivo seja selecionado.

Neste caso em que o usuário decidiu não importar o arquivo, você deve "pular" o código que faz a importação.

O método `Application.GetOpenFilename` retorna o nome do arquivo se ele for selecionado e retorna `Fase` se o usuário clicou em "cancelar" na caixa de diálogo (é, eu sei, meio estranho).

Então você pode testar o retorno de GetOpenFilename e só executar o código de importação se o retorno for diferente de `False`. Mais ou menos assim:

```
dirArquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text File, *.txt")

if dirArquivo <> False then
    'código para importar aqui.
end if
```

Comment: Muito bom. Funcionou perfeitamente.

Answer (score 2):

O método [Application.GetOpenFilename](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/office/ff834966(v=office.15).aspx) retorna um valor do tipo `Variant`, que pode ser um arquivo, uma matriz de arquivos ou o valor booleano `false` caso a operação seja cancelada, então você pode fazer uma verificação antes iniciar a importação, algo assim:

```
Public Sub btnImportarTXT_Click()

    ' Sub para importar arquivo .TXT

    Dim Dir As String

    dirArquivo = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Text File, *.txt")

    If dirArquivo <> False Then ' verifica se o usuário cancelou a importação
        With Sheets("Extract").QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & dirArquivo, _
        Destination:=Range("Extract!$A$1"))
            .Name = "extract"
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 1252
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With

        ' Worksheets("Extract").Protect UserInterfaceOnly:=True

        MsgBox "Arquivo importado!", vbOKOnly, "Sucesso!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Importação cancelada!", vbOKOnly, "Aviso!"
    End If

End Sub
```